# Exception of Glassmapper after upgrading to Sitecore 8.2

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.2

I am getting the below exception after we upgraded to Sitecore 8.2 and glass mapper version 4.3.4.197.

> Exception : Message = "Failed to find configuration for parent item
>   type Sitecore.Data.Items.Item"

My code below :

Saving item into master database

```
Parent Item type = Sitecore.Data.Items
var newItem = sitecoreContext.Create(parentItem , fixed);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and found that if you cast your parent item to a specific template it seems to work.  For example, instead of

`Item parent = sitecoreService.GetItem<Item>(GUID);
 ChildTemplateType childItem = sitecoreService.Create(parent, childData);`

use:

`Item parent = sitecoreService.GetItem<Item>(GUID);
 ParentTemplateType parentCasted = sitecoreService.Cast<ParentTemplateType>(parent);
 ChildTemplateType childItem = sitecoreService.Create(parentCasted, childData);`